# Instant messaging onMessageFailed

Tags: sinch

I want to send some push notifications to the user when the message is not received.

I see that I have only this option: `onMessageDelivered` which works great, but how can I notify the user if he didn't read the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism for knowing read or not. Only delivered